Why is the RPS Fluctuating Dramatically During Locust Stress Testing and Not Reaching the Server as Specified?
I’m using Locust for stress testing my application API, but I’m experiencing dramatic fluctuations in the Requests Per Second (RPS). For example, the RPS goes up to 2000 and then drops to 2 RPS in 2 seconds, which is not consistent with the expected behavior based on my code. Additionally, I checked the OCI logs and noticed that not all requests are reaching the server as specified in the code, resulting in inconsistent request handling.
Here is my current Locust test script:
class UserBehavior(HttpUser):
    host = "https://example.com/api/"

    wait_time = between(2, 2)
    @task
    def one(self):

        actions = [
            (self.client.post, "createg", {"goal": "New Goal", "amount": random.randint(100, 1000)}),
            (self.client.post, "listg"),
        ]
        action = random.choice(actions)
        with self.client.request(action[0].__name__.upper(), action[1], json=action[2] if len(action) > 2 else None, catch_response=True) as response:
            if response.status_code != 200:
                response.failure(f"Failed with status code: {response.status_code}")
    @task
    def two(self):

        actions = [
            (self.client.post, "newd", {"amount": random.randint(100, 500)}),
            (self.client.post, "listd"),
            (self.client.post, "requestd", {"amount": random.randint(50, 200)}),
            (self.client.post, "listw")
        ]
        action = random.choice(actions)
        with self.client.request(action[0].__name__.upper(), action[1], json=action[2] if len(action) > 2 else None, catch_response=True) as response:
            if response.status_code != 200:
                response.failure(f"Failed with status code: {response.status_code}")
    @task
    def three(self):

        actions = [
            (self.client.post, "v1/tickets/create", {"subject": "Issue", "description": "Description"}),
            (self.client.post, "v1/tickets/list"),
            (self.client.post, "v1/tickets/reply", {"message": "Reply"})
        ]
        action = random.choice(actions)
        with self.client.request(action[0].__name__.upper(), action[1], json=action[2] if len(action) > 2 else None, catch_response=True) as response:
            if response.status_code != 200:
                response.failure(f"Failed with status code: {response.status_code}")
env = Environment(user_classes=[UserBehavior])
runner = env.create_local_runner()

web_ui = env.create_web_ui("0.0.0.0", 8090)

env.events.init.fire(environment=env, runner=runner, web_ui=web_ui)

gevent.spawn(stats_history, env.runner)

def start_test():
    num_users = 20000

    spawn_rate = 67  
    runner.start(user_count=num_users, spawn_rate=spawn_rate)
@events.test_start.add_listener
def on_test_start(environment, **kwargs):

    start_test()
    gevent.spawn_later(3600, lambda: runner.quit())
runner.greenlet.join()

web_ui.stop()


here is RPS chart from locust
Any insights or suggestions on what might be causing this issue and how to resolve it would be greatly appreciated.

Hi! What are your response times like? if your response times are all over the place then this might cause variations in RPS. You could try using constant_pacing instead of between() as wait time to stabilize rps (and launching more users)

The response times are very erratic, with significant spikes. The median response time and the 95th percentile response time vary greatly, reaching up to 1,000,000 ms at some points. Is this causing the fluctuations in RPS? is using constant_pacing will help resolve this issue?

Yes! Use constant pacing with a high enough value and a lot of Users to get a more stable rps. If the system under test is over its limit, it may not help though. I’m writing a blog post right now detailing this problem and will link it when it is done :)

Here's the link to my post: https://medium.com/locust-cloud/locusts-and-honey-badgers-closed-vs-open-workload-models-in-load-testing-9f59abfc6d9f
